# XMLHttpRequest popup not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I happen to be having a problem with the following function below.

```
    function searchPreviousRecord(last_name, first_name, dob) {
       if (!last_name || !first_name || !dob)
            return;

       var url = '/wp-content/themes/sample/sync/api/search.php';

       url += '?first_name=' + first_name + '&last_name=' + last_name + '&dob=' + usToIntlDate(dob);

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        http.open("GET", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        http.responseType = 'json';

     }
```

What it is supposed to do that get records based on first name, last name, and the dob.

It is working on Chrome, FF, and the Edge Browser. However, on IE11 it is not working. Is there a substitute that I can use in IE11 for XMLHttpRequest()?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: You need to first detect IE11, and handle the response in another way, like text for example `data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);`

Comment: And you never `send()` this request? Surprised it does anything anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing an http.send() at the end.